# Webpack Appends To Page With Every HMR Update

Tags: webpack, angular5, webpack-hmr

I have updated to Webpack 3.10.0 and now everytime the page is updated using Hot Module Replacement the previous content of the page gets wrapped in a div and left on the page below the new content. The old content loses all the styles and just makes the page larger and larger with every update.

```
<app _nghost-c6="" ng-version="5.2.2"></app>
<app _nghost-c4="" ng-version="5.2.2"></app>
<app _nghost-c2="" ng-version="5.2.2"></app>
<app _nghost-c0="" ng-version="5.2.2"></app>
```

Has anyone run into this issue before?